# On small screen, Signle Page AMP-HTML's sidebar menu closing issue

Tags: html, amp-html

I have created a single page site, when menu items are clicked, the page scroll to anchors defined in page. The menus are working fine on large screen (desktop) and when clicked the page scroll to the section, but on small screen (mobile) AMP sidebar menu doesn't close after tapping on a menu item and if you press the close button, then it doesn't go to the section of page that was selected in the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found at [this issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/4184) on Github:

> `amp-sidebar` pops the history when it's canceled so the navigation is canceled

it's a known bug with single page anchor navigation, but:

> This should be fixed in the next release

the relative [fix branch](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/5961) is now (2016-11-30) under review